# pandas Series to json array

Tags: python, json

I am trying to prepare json array in python for processing in PHP. I derived results fom the 'for' loop:

```
for Pr in range(150,370,20):
   for Te in range(250,320,10):
       maxvGuess = np.array([0.04])
       y = fsolve(F_vol, maxvGuess, Pr)*1000
       forphp = pd.Series({'Volume': str(y).lstrip('[').rstrip(']'), 'Pressure': Pr, 'Temperature': Te})
       arr = forphp.to_json()
       print(arr)
```

I am getting results like this:

```
{'Volume': ' 57.23582288', 'Pressure': 150, 'Temperature': 250} 
{'Volume': ' 59.62839406', 'Pressure': 150, 'Temperature': 260} 
{'Volume': ' 61.98900065', 'Pressure': 150, 'Temperature': 270} 
{'Volume': ' 64.32323062', 'Pressure': 150, 'Temperature': 280} 
........
```

I need a json structure with the above results in a list something like this, in order to decode it in PHP:

```
[
{'Volume': ' 57.23582288', 'Pressure': 150, 'Temperature': 250}, 
{'Volume': ' 59.62839406', 'Pressure': 150, 'Temperature': 260}, 
{'Volume': ' 61.98900065', 'Pressure': 150, 'Temperature': 270}, 
{'Volume': ' 64.32323062', 'Pressure': 150, 'Temperature': 280}, 
........
]
```

I've tried many combinations (data frame, json.dumps etc.) and went through many posts, but just cannot figure out how to make correct jason array. I am not a programmer and apologize in advance if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want but try doing this:

```
l=[]
for Pr in range(150,370,20):
    for Te in range(250,320,10):
        maxvGuess = np.array([0.04])
        y = fsolve(F_vol, maxvGuess, Pr)*1000
        forphp = pd.Series({'Volume': str(y).lstrip('[').rstrip(']'), 'Pressure': Pr, 'Temperature': Te})
        l.append(dict(forphp))

jsonobj = json.dumps(l)
print (jsonobj)
```

Comment: It's not good to name variables a builtin keyword, you named `list` which is overwriting the builtin keyword

Comment: @U9-Forward haha yea, noticed the mistake as soon as you edited the post.

Comment: Yes, it works.  ReKx, you are amazing. Just for clarity - i am exporting result of this Python calculation (it is a function, but this is just a tail end) to PHP for the website calc. For that, I needed proper json array (for PHP json_decode). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Always happy to help.